# Spring boot - use a configurable value on a @Qualifier

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two implementations for one interface, i want to choose what implementation to use based on a configuration. The qualifier solution did not work as it is initialized prior to the configuration. How can I achieve this?

Comment: does it work without the qualifier?

Comment: Could you please describe your use-case? 

Qualifiers are used when there are more than one bean of the same type co-exist in Application context and you want to inject a particular bean. In this case no need for dynamic configuration usually, you chose among a set of predefined values for injecting the bean with qualifier

Comment: @JoseMartinez Without it, i will have to add constructor dependencies manually, which is not nice in a spring project

Comment: @MarkBramnik I have two different implementations of a job and it is possible to change the type every month so if configurable, less deployments and code changes are made.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read Qualifier from property file in spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50208018/how-to-read-qualifier-from-property-file-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding to the main app class the two implementations autowired then define a bean for each:

```
@Autowired
TypeOneImpl typeOneImpl
@Bean(name = "typeOneImpl")
public InterfaceRClass getTypeOneImpl()
{
    return typeOneImpl;
}
```

Then in the other class I defined a config field

```
@Value("${myClass.type}")
private String configClassType;
// the below should be defined in constructor
private final InterfaceRClass interfaceRClassElement ;
```

And added a setter for it with @Autowired annotation:

```
@Autowired
public void setMyClassType(ApplicationContext context) {
    interfaceRClassElement = (InterfaceRClass) context.getBean(configClassType);
}
```

In configuration, the value should be typeOneImpl (typeTwoImpl is added for an additional implementation)

Answer (score 14):

I've got your comment:

> I have two different implementations of a job and it is possible to change the type every month so if configurable, less deployments and code changes are made.

You might have something like this:

```
 interface Job {
     void foo();
 }

 class JobA implements Job {
     void foo() {...}
 }

 class JobB implements Job {
     void foo() {...}
 }

 class JobExecutor {
    
    Job job;
    // autowired constructor
    public JobExecutor(Job job) {this.job = job;}
 }
```

And, if I got you right, it doesn't make sense to load two beans simultaneously in the same application context.

But if so, then `@Qualifier` is not a right tool for the job.

I suggest using conditions that are integrated into spring boot instead:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "job.name", havingValue = "jobA")
    @Bean 
    public Job jobA() {
         return new JobA();
    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "job.name", havingValue = "jobB")
    @Bean 
    public Job jobB() {
         return new JobB();
    }
    @Bean
    public JobExecutor jobExecutor(Job job) {
       return new JobExecutor(job);
    }
}
```

Now in `application.properties` (or yaml whatever you have) define:

```
 job.name = jobA # or jobB
```

Of course, instead of `jobA/jobB` you might use more self-explanatory names from your business domain.

Answer (score 4):

You could pull it off with if you fiddle around with Spring java-based config a bit, where you programmatically decide the right implementation based on a config value:

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppContext implements EnvironmentAware{

    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(final Environment env) {
       this.env = env;
    }

    @Bean
    public MyBeanByConfig myBeanByConfig(){
        String configValue = env.getProperty("mybean.config");

        if(configValue.equals("1")){
           return new MyBeanByConfigOne();
        }else{
           return new MyBeanByConfigTwo();
        }
    }
}
```

and on the qualifier you would put:

```
@Qualifier("myBeanByConfig")
```

you may need to add `@ComponentScan` and `@PropertySource` on the configuration class also.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have an interface:

```java
public interface Foo {
    void doSomething();
}
```

And 2 implementations:

```java
public class Foo_A implements Foo {
    @Override
    doSomething() {...}
}

public class Foo_B implements Foo {
    @Override
    doSomething() {...}
}
```

Now you want to use Foo_A/Foo_B depending on a property value in your properties file:

```yaml
foo_name: "A"
```

The simplest way I found to do this:

1. First, you qualify your implementations

```java
@Component("Foo_A")
public class Foo_A implements Foo {
    @Override
    doSomething() {...}
}

@Component("Foo_B")
public class Foo_B implements Foo {
    @Override
    doSomething() {...}
}
```

2. Then, wherever you gonna use this (class Bar,  for example), you can just use the @Qualifier to specify the implementations you are instantiating and get the value from the property with the @Value. Then, inside the method, with a simple if/else statement, you use the property value to decide which implementation you're going to call.

```java
public class Bar {

    @Value("${foo_name}")
    private String fooName;

    @Qualifier("Foo_A")
    private Foo fooA;

    @Qualifier("Foo_B")
    private Foo fooB;

    public void doSomething() {
        if (fooName.equals("A")) {
            fooA.doSomething();
        } else {
            fooB.doSomething();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

knowing that IOC works fine throught constructor maybe I would do something like this:

```
@Component
public class JobExecutor implements WhateverService {


    private final Job myJob;

    public JobExecutor(Map<String, Job> allJobImpls,
                       @Value("${myClass.type}") final String classType) {

        this.myJob = allImpls.get(classType);
    }

    public X myAction() {
         // some code
         return myJob.whatever(); //for example
    }
}
```